# Code to load file stops working from one minute to the other matlab eeglab

Tags: matlab, eeglab

I use this for loop to export my set file to .txt.

```
for i = 1:length(files)
    filename = files(i).name;
    
    EEG = pop_loadset('filename', filename, 'filepath', directory_name);
    
    EEG = eeg_checkset( EEG );
    EEG = pop_export(EEG,fullfile(directory_name, [filename(1:end-4),'.txt']),'transpose','on','separator',',','precision',7);
end
```

But this is less my concern than the fact that the code worked well, but suddenly, it give me this error.

```
Reference to non-existent field 'setname'.

Error in eeg_checkset (line 689)
    if ~isempty(EEG.setname)

Error in pop_loadset (line 204)
    EEG = eeg_checkset(EEG);

Error in save_as_txt (line 43)
    EEG = pop_loadset('filename', filename, 'filepath', directory_name);
```

I tried to reopen matlab, but it still gives the same error again and again.... Also when I use other scripts that start the same way, it is not working anymore.

DO you have any suggestions?
Thank you very much!!

Comment: This just tells you that your structure EEG does not have a field named setname. In fact, I assume that in the previous line, `EEG = pop_loadset(blablabla);`, EEG is empty because for some reason you fail to read the file.

Comment: Thank you very much!! I saw that in my last run I accidentally overwrote my files!! I fixed this error and it works well!! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you very much @Matteo V for your reply: "This just tells you that your structure EEG does not have a field named setname. In fact, I assume that in the previous line, `EEG = pop_loadset(blablabla);`, EEG is empty because for some reason you fail to read the file."

I saw that in my last run I accidentally overwrote my files!! I fixed this error and it works well!! :)